# ResponseEntity is always null in Mockito while calling function from a service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have created a service class

```java
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMethod() {
        EntityClass entity = new EntityClass();
        //Some operations to manipulate entity
        return new ResponseEntity<>("entity", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the object in a test class using Mockito:

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Slf4j
public class SomeServiceTest {
    @Mock
    SomeService someService;
    @Test
    public void getMethodSomeService(){
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity=someService.getMethod();
        log.debug("{}", responseEntity);
    }
}
```

However, `responseEntity` is always `null`. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Why the value I got is always null?

Comment: you should accept an answer or add information on further issues.

Comment: @Jeppz None of the answer worked for me. I dropped this approach and followed a new one. I usually let the votes from other users decide the applicability of answers. At the end of the day, Q&A on [so] or anywhere on the Stack Exchange network are not only for the questioner. It could be a case where answers didn't work for me but would work for other users/future visitors. Since I believe the question was clear enough and I dropped this approach, there's nothing to be added.

Comment: Adding "*I dropped this approach*" as an answer or edit won't yield anything useful. Even such answers are very low quality answers. Also, I think accepting an answer means "*this answer worked for me*", and is completely optional. So, from my end no further action is required, I think,

Answer (score 1):

By writing

```
@Mock
SomeService someService;
```

You have created a mock, all method calls to that mock will return null unless you tell it to do otherwise with something like this

```
when(someService.someMethod(any())).thenReturn("something");
```

Because of this `someService.getMethod()` will always return null.
You are probably looking to not use a mock in this case, mocks are usually used to prevent calls to other objects that aren't supposed to be part of the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking means replacing a concrete implementation with something you can manipulate from the outside. If you want to test your `SomeServiceImpl`, you can just create a new instance.

```java
SomeService service = new SomeServiceImpl();
```

This instance can then be tested.

---

If your `SomeService` had a dependency to let's say another Service, you might need to mock this dependency in order to control its behaviour.

```java
@Mock
OtherService dependency;
SomeService someService = new SomeServiceImpl(dependency);
```

Comment: Did you miss `new` before `SomeServiceImpl`?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Currently I am not working with Java, therefore I am not used to the syntax anymore. I corrected it.